# subprocess error that cause unhandled error

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running newsplease project from `https://github.com/fhamborg/news-please/blob/master/newsplease/__main__.py` from `subprocess`

```
         cmd = ["python",r"/media/dhruvagupta/F428F6FA28F6BB26/backup dhruva/python/New folder/training/news-please-master/news-please-master/newsplease/__main__.py","-c /newsplease/config/"]
        j = psutil.Popen(cmd)
```

i am getting this error

```
            Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/dhruvagupta/F428F6FA28F6BB26/backup dhruva/python/New folder/training/news-please-master/news-please-master/newsplease/single_crawler.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.process.start()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 293, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1272, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1281, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 902, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/reactor.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._a, **self._kw)
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 122, in _next_request
    if not self._next_request_from_scheduler(spider):
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 149, in _next_request_from_scheduler
    request = slot.scheduler.next_request()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 71, in next_request
    request = self._dqpop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 106, in _dqpop
    d = self.dqs.pop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queuelib/pqueue.py", line 43, in pop
    m = q.pop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/squeues.py", line 19, in pop
    s = super(SerializableQueue, self).pop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queuelib/queue.py", line 161, in pop
    size, = struct.unpack(self.SIZE_FORMAT, self.f.read())
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

and another error

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/dhruvagupta/F428F6FA28F6BB26/backup dhruva/python/New folder/training/news-please-master/news-please-master/newsplease/single_crawler.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.process.start()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 293, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1272, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1281, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 902, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/reactor.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._a, **self._kw)
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 122, in _next_request
    if not self._next_request_from_scheduler(spider):
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 149, in _next_request_from_scheduler
    request = slot.scheduler.next_request()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 71, in next_request
    request = self._dqpop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 106, in _dqpop
    d = self.dqs.pop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queuelib/pqueue.py", line 43, in pop
    m = q.pop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/squeues.py", line 19, in pop
    s = super(SerializableQueue, self).pop()
  File "/home/dhruvagupta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queuelib/queue.py", line 162, in pop
    self.f.seek(-size-self.SIZE_SIZE, os.SEEK_END)
exceptions.IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please correct your formatting

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh could you please add guidance towards to docs for beginners

Comment: yes, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh above command is what i wrote it produced the given error